# How can I see the implementation code for "and"?

Tags: haskell

I have found the definition for and, on the internet but I couldnt find the actual implementation of and. I did search for some sort of prelude haskell file on my computer but it didn't return anything which could be opened in a text editor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search for Haskell functions, like so:

http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=and

The function links take you to the library module where the function was defined, and in this case the link for `and` takes us to here:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:and

You then click on the `Source` link to the right of the function name and it takes you to the source of that function.  For the case of `and` it links us to here:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#and

```
and                     :: [Bool] -> Bool
or                      :: [Bool] -> Bool
#ifdef USE_REPORT_PRELUDE
and                     =  foldr (&&) True
or                      =  foldr (||) False
#else
and []          =  True
and (x:xs)      =  x && and xs
or []           =  False
or (x:xs)       =  x || or xs
#endif
```

You'll see that `and` actually has two definitions.  One is the Standard Prelude definition, which is only enabled if you compile with the `USE_REPORT_PRELUDE` flag, and the other is the definition the Prelude is usually compiled with, which is typically more optimized.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I have no clue.  I just assume the people who optimize the base libraries had some good reason to type all those extra characters.

Comment: Funny, there is a RULES pragma after that code that essentially tells it to pretend to use the USE_REPORT_PRELUDE version for build/foldr rewriting

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect to find the source code in your local distribution of Haskell - which is probably Haskell Platform. Instead, go to [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and search for the function. One way, which is what you want, is to search by its name, `and`, go to its Haddock, and then click "source."

On Hoogle, you can also search by type signature, ie. `[Bool] -> Bool` which you'll probably find yourself doing quite often.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html

`and` is defined as `foldr (&&) True`.